# vowel (not) matching changes with excluding digits

Tags: regex

I'm totally new to regex. I'm trying to match two consecutive consonants, which means I have to exclude vowels and digits.
However, I cannot manage to exclude the digits.

The following code works and excludes vowels (but still matches double digits):

```
 ([^aeiou]|[^AEIOU])\1
```

However, as soon as I enter:

```
([^aeiou]|[^AEIOU]|[^0-9])\1
```

every double character gets matched, including double vowels and of course double digits.
The only way I can avoid matching double digits is when I do it only for digits:

```
([^0-9])\1
```

What's happening?

Thank you!

Comment: `[^aeiou]` matches any character but the ones in the character class. You might need just the consonant character class like `[b-df-hj-np-tv-z]` (or a case-insensitive `[b-df-hj-np-tv-zB-DF-HJ-NP-TV-Z]`).

Answer (score 1):

Try this expression:

```
([^aeiou^0-9]|[^AEIOU^0-9])\1
```

I have tried on regex101.com and it have worked fine with the global modifier.